# Creating a FILE structure using a byte array

Tags: c, arrays, file, byte, sdl

The SDL_image API allows you to pass in a FILE* and get an SDL_Surface*.

Currently, I'm designing a map archive.
One of the files is a tileset. It will be a PNG image (Great format with it's lossless compression).

I'm reading all the bytes from the file and putting them into a buffer (a byte array).

How would I go about creating a FILE* out of a byte array?
I don't care if I have to modify anything inside the FILE structure that's meant to be private, that was my initial approach, but I was facing difficulties figuring out what a couple of the members of the struct are for. (I'm referring to the _iobuf struct)

**Edit**

You have to understand that I'm using zlib, meaning that when reading from the uncompressed files in the archive, I'm using the function unzReadCurrentFile.
I don't know if there's a way to get a FILE* directly while using zlib.

Comment: There you go. http://pastebin.com/NggCLEVg

Comment: "The SDL_image API allows you to pass in a FILE* and get an SDL_Surface*." Which one? I struggle to find a function in SDL_Image that takes a `FILE*`.

Comment: @jrok: IMG_LoadPNG_RW(SDL_RWFromFP(myFILEPointer, 0)) so it's not actually a direct conversion ;o

Comment: @ViniyoShouta I know, I have access to the stdio.h file :o

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misunderstood `figuring out what a couple of the members of the struct are FOR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's impossibru. A `FILE*` is just that- a file. You can't do anything about the fact that the SDL API uses C I/O and therefore is approximately as useful as a dead fish.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I can write the bytes to the disk and then read them as a FILE* :O
Should this work as expected?

Comment: Anyway, I found the solution, thank you to everyone who took the time to respond.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Well, you can also use `mmap` to turn the bytes into a "real" file without even going to disk. EDIT: oops, sorry for the dead post.